# Is there an inequality relating the difference between two random variable and the difference between their distribution functions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X, Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be two random variables with respective cumulative distribution functions $F_X, F_Y$ respectively. I was wondering whether there's an inequality possible relating the two functions:

(1) $|X-Y|: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and (2) $|F_X - F_Y|: \mathbb{R} \to [0,2]$. (*Note that the domains of (1), (2) are different!)* In both of the cases, you can replace the pointwise difference by some kind of norm (e.g. sup norm, $L^p$ norm etc.).

Now, I'm aware that: $F_X - F_Y \ne F_{X-Y}$, but still hoping that if $|F_X - F_Y|$ is small on $ K \subset \Omega$, then $|X-Y|$ will also be small on a neighborhood of $X(K)$, and vice versa. Or, at least a form of probabilistic inequality like:

If $|F_X-F_Y| \le \epsilon$ uniformly on a compact subinterval $I \in \mathbb{R},$ then there exists a $\delta \equiv \delta(\epsilon) > 0$ so that:
$P[\{\omega \in X^{-1}(K): |X(\omega) - Y(\omega)| > \delta] \le \epsilon$

It's perhaps not possible in general, but is there a condition on $X, Y$ that'll make it possible? Thanks!!

Comment: So, if say $X,Y$ are i.i.d. standard Gaussians, then $|X-Y|$ is a half-normal distribution, and is non-trivial (has non-zero norms, no matter which reasonable norm you pick), but of course $|F_X-F_Y|=0$.

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks - that's useful. Yes this is why we study iid r.v.'s I guess, they all have exactly same distribution/density but they can take values as different as possible!

Comment: @ClementC. How about the converse? If $X, Y$ are close, would that mean $F_X, F_Y$ are close? Can assume independenc eif needed, but not necessarily. If independent, then $F_{X-Y}= F_X * F_{-Y}$ (convolution), but does it yield anything?

Comment: Without independence: you may want to look at the coupling characterization of Wasserstein distance (see e.g., [this](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~souravc/Lecture2.pdf)). It has some implication on the Kolmogorov distance (supremum norm between cumulative distribution functions).